# How to create an object of an interface?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I wanted to implement the class EmailMessage to my app, to allow you to send email
[EmailMessage Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmessage.aspx)
The created object has a property called "To". Must be an object of type IList.  
How do I create a list with that interface to use the property "To"?

```
public void Metodo()
{
    EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage();
    message.Subject = "Ok";
    message.To=//??
}
```

Comment: Classes and interfaces are two distinct and different things.   You don't implement a class, you implement an interface.  You instantiate a class (create an instance of).  Your question is not very clear....what are you trying to do?  Can you post some code?

Comment: have you tried anything?  What problems are you running into?

Comment: You don't.  `To` is clearly marked as read-only, so you will never assign it.  You need to do `message.To.Add(...)` instead.

Comment: Had completely wrong answer... deleted... Please use `IList.Add` to add items to the list (since list it is already created for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmessage.aspx) you listed:

> Property: To
>   Access Type: Read-only
>   Description: Gets the direct recipients of the email message.

Because `To` is an `IList<T>` it exposes the method `Add` so you can simply call this:

```
email.To.Add(emailRecipient);
```